# Can't connect php file with Xcode through iPhone

Tags: php, ios, iphone, xcode

I am working on an app which includes a database. I use PHP to connect to a MySQl database. Here is my connection code:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost/Workspace/Twitter/register.php")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let body = "Username=\(UsernameTXF.text!.lowercased())&password=\(PassTXT.text!.lowercased())"
request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
     print("error=\(error)")
     return
}
```

This code works flawlessly when I run it on simulator,but when I run it on iPhone it gives me following error:

> error=Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x17425dbb0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost/Workspace/Twitter/register.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost/Workspace/Twitter/register.php, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"localhost" on your iPhone is an entirely different thing than "localhost" on your desktop running a simulator. If you want to run this code on your iPhone, specify a domain that can be reached *from the phone.* I.e., use a numeric IP address or specify a domain where your web service is running.

Comment: I need to buy a domain for that?

Comment: If your phone is connecting to the internet using wifi, you could probably just use the IP address of your workstation -- but this would only work for phones that are connected to your LAN where your web service is running and. If the phone connects to the internet using your cell phone service (e.g., G4 or LTS via Verizon or something) then your web service must be hosted by a publicly visible computer on the broader internet. You might be able to use DynDNS for your workstation -  or not.

Comment: Okay.In future if my app will be in appstore is this the optimal and good way of inserting data to mysql?

Comment: If you want this app to be in the app store then you must choose. Do you yourself want to access the data being stored by others? Or is the data necessarily shared? If so, YES you'll need a domain. Or alternatively, if each user only needs to store their own data then you could probably use a local db like SQLLite or something like that.

Comment: PS to the OP - Apple is going to eventually force everyone to https.... https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12212016b

Comment: Indeed, quite heuristic