# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server."

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting this error:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the
>   server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000250530 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)"

Below is my code:

```
    -(NSMutableURLRequest*)createRequest:(NSURL*)url data:(NSData*)postData
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];  
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned 
                           long)[postData length]];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
        forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    return request;
}

-(void)requestForUserRegister:(NSString*)name password:(NSString*)password phone:(NSString*)phone email:(NSString*)email
{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:3000/*******/"]];

    NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&password=%@&phone=%@&email=%@",name,password,phone,email];

    NSString *post =[data stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
   // NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self createRequest:url data:postData];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if(error)
        {
            [self.apiDelegate responseDidFail:self];
        }else
        {
            @try {
                self.value = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                [self.apiDelegate responseDidSecceed:self];
            } @catch (NSException *exception) {

                [self.apiDelegate responseDidFail:self];
            }
        }

    }]
     resume];
  }
```

Comment: are you added the transport security in your app

Comment: might this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/42553810/3548469

Comment: yes. check this: <dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>

Comment: @Dev_Tandel thanks but i am running on simulator.

Comment: check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40047949/3548469

Comment: still not working @Dev_Tandel

Comment: will you check your url if it is working in Postman collection?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41575879/3548469